# search for a phrase in Sphinx

Tags: php, sphinx

I'm not able to search for a phrase in Sphinx 2.2.9 using extended syntax.
In PHP, for example, I'd like use a code that sounds like this:

```
<?php
    require ("sphinxapi.php");
    $cl = new SphinxClient ();
    $cl->setServer("127.0.0.1", 9312);
    // $cl->SetMatchMode (SPH_MATCH_PHRASE); CAN'T USE! DEPRECATED IN VERSION 2.2.9
    $MORETHANAWORD = "to be or not to be";

    // some smart code...

    echo "Ok, in your " . $docs . " docs the phrase " . $MORETHANAWORD . " is present " . $hits . "times.";     
?>
```

Comment: Can you use SphinxQL instead?  Should be a fairly simple MATCH() query there ...

Comment: Also depreciated doesnt mean you CANT use it, just that shouldnt rely on it in the future. It WILL be removed, it hasnt been removed yet. (the whole of the API is deprecated in favour of SphinxQL already)

Comment: I understand that you can use SphinxQL only with MySQL and PostgreSQL. I use Firebird+ODBC.

Answer (score 0):

```
$res = $cl->Query("\"$MORETHANAWORD\"", 'index_name');
$docs = $res['total_found'];
```

Can't get $hits. Sphinx doesnt tell you how many times the phrase occurs (in cases its in a document multiple times) - just the number of matching documents.